# Getting base number derived from multiple (1 to 4)

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have both php and javascript function that receive an integer and return a value from 1 to 4,
here is how my function works :

- in 1 -> out 1,
- in 2 -> out 2,
- in 3 -> out 3,
- in 4 -> out 4,
- in 5 -> out 1,
- ...
- in 9 -> out 1,
- ...

and here is my current function:

```
function getGid(pid){ 
  gid = 0;
  while (pid > 4 ) { 
    pid = pid-4; 
      gid++; 
  }
  return gid;
}
```

and I want to know if I chose a good method or is there another way to do that more simple?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, variables in PHP start with `$`

Next, counting in programming starts with **0**, not with **1**. So, the most quick and elegant solution would be

```
function gid($pid) {
    return $pid % 4;
}

echo gid(1); // outputs 1
echo gid(2); // outputs 2
echo gid(3); // outputs 3
echo gid(4); // outputs 0
echo gid(5); // outputs 1
echo gid(6); // outputs 2
echo gid(7); // outputs 3
echo gid(8); // outputs 0
```

And I would stick to it, but you do not want the usual `0,1,2,3`, you want `4` instead of `0`, so...

```
function gid($pid) {
    return ($pid % 4 == 0)? 4 : $pid % 4 ;
}

echo gid(1); // outputs 1
echo gid(2); // outputs 2
echo gid(3); // outputs 3
echo gid(4); // outputs 4
echo gid(5); // outputs 1
echo gid(6); // outputs 2
echo gid(7); // outputs 3
echo gid(8); // outputs 4
```

Your Javascript function would be similar:

```
function gid(pid) {
    return (pid % 4 == 0)? 4 : pid % 4 ;
}
```

Comment: many thanks, i don't know why i wrote "php function" because i have a "javascript function"

Comment: You say your question is pure javascript and has nothing to do with PHP?

Comment: yes and no, i use same function both in php and in javascript, but in question i wrote "php function" and I gave as example a javascript function.